# remove event of keydown from selector doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use keydown on one of my element, but I want to unbind it if it doesn't fit into my condition. But I used `off()` and `unbind` it doesn't seem to work. The alert of still got trigged, I wonder why.

```
if (imgDOM.naturalWidth > imgDOM.naturalHeight) {

  $('#caption').attr('maxlength', 220);

  $("#caption").keydown(function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode == 10 || e.keyCode == 13)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('Landscape photo is allowed to have only single line of message.');
      return false;
    }
  });

} else {
  $('#caption').off('keydown', function() { //this won't work
    limit_lines_for_potrait();
  })
}
```

Comment: maybe this condition `if (imgDOM.naturalWidth > imgDOM.naturalHeight) {` is always true.

Comment: @vher2 No, for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) as if it's listening for a new event, the function handler in this case is a refernce to the function to unbind, not a function that's run when after unbinding. `limit_lines_for_potrait()` should be the function you want to remove, but your original bind uses an anonymous function which you can't reference.

Assuming you have no other binds on the same element and event, you could simplify this to: `$('#caption').off('keydown');` Which will unbind all listeners for that element and event type.

To run the function after, simply call that function:

```
} else {
  $('#caption').off('keydown');
  limit_lines_for_potrait();
}
```

Since the unbind isn't a listener, you don't need to wait for a callback, it will always be executed before the next line runs.

Comment: I want to remove the keydown binding, and run limit_lines_for_potrait

Comment: @MariaJane I've updated the answer you can simply run the function manually after unbinding the event (As shown by vher2) Since the unbind isn't a listener, you don't need to wait for a callback, it will allways be executed before the next line runs

Comment: it worked, but why the callback didn't work like the way it should?

Comment: @MariaJane Because it's not a callback, it's effectively saying "I want to unbind this function from this event", there is no need for a callback from this command as it executes immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the anonymous function in `off`, it will solve your problem.

```
....

} else {
    $('#caption').off('keydown');
    limit_lines_for_potrait();
}
```

Comment: off doesn't have a callback?

Comment: It's not a callback, as explained by @DBS